# How to write a MongoDB lookup query between 2 collections using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

For example, create an example collection classes with the following document:

```
db.classes.insert( [
   { _id: 1, title: "Reading is ...", enrollmentlist: [ "giraffe2", "pandabear", "artie" ], days: ["M", "W", "F"] },
   { _id: 2, title: "But Writing ...", enrollmentlist: [ "giraffe1", "artie" ], days: ["T", "F"] }
])
```

Create another collection members with the following documents:

```
db.members.insert( [
   { _id: 1, name: "artie", joined: new Date("2016-05-01"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 2, name: "giraffe", joined: new Date("2017-05-01"), status: "D" },
   { _id: 3, name: "giraffe1", joined: new Date("2017-10-01"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 4, name: "panda", joined: new Date("2018-10-11"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 5, name: "pandabear", joined: new Date("2018-12-01"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 6, name: "giraffe2", joined: new Date("2018-12-01"), status: "D" }
])
```

The following aggregation operation joins documents in the classes collection with the members collection, matching on the members field to the name field:

```
db.classes.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "members",
            localField: "enrollmentlist",
            foreignField: "name",
            as: "enrollee_info"
        }
   }
])
```

The operation returns the following:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "title" : "Reading is ...",
   "enrollmentlist" : [ "giraffe2", "pandabear", "artie" ],
   "days" : [ "M", "W", "F" ],
   "enrollee_info" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "artie", "joined" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" },
      { "_id" : 5, "name" : "pandabear", "joined" : ISODate("2018-12-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" },
      { "_id" : 6, "name" : "giraffe2", "joined" : ISODate("2018-12-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "D" }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "title" : "But Writing ...",
   "enrollmentlist" : [ "giraffe1", "artie" ],
   "days" : [ "T", "F" ],
   "enrollee_info" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "artie", "joined" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" },
      { "_id" : 3, "name" : "giraffe1", "joined" : ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" }
   ]
}
```

How would you write this in Java with MongoDB?

Comment: A little more clarification would be helpful. Do you want to read the collections from mongo, but join them in java.  Or do you want mongo to do the join, and read the result into your java program?

Comment: @Erik
I would like a Java code example of how to write  an example of<br/>
 `MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("classes");`
`collection.aggregate( <lookup code here>);// example of how to do $lookup:{....}`